# SSL Certificate X.509 Export

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to use a Web Service but I have many doubts about the certificates, I'm quite a novice in this topic, The team that developed the web services sent me a document where explains how to use it but to enable the connection, I need to USE a certificate (X.509), I generated p7b certificate from they website and I imported that certificate in my local environment, Using Keytool -import it generate a JKS file but they warn that I should install "Entrust" (Root and Intermediate)  certificates that they provide me I used keytool -import with these .cer files and the command generated one .JKS for each file, I installed those cer too, my question is:

- To use that web service Which certificate file I need to attach in my implementation logic in java, the jks or p7b ?
- How I can use this certificate in all the Test environment? (I don't know if this certificate can be use only in the PC that generates the CSR).

I'm trying to simulate the call with the SOAPUI app i'm getting the authentication error so Probably something is worng with the certificate.

He implemented all using windows certificate store and .NET they can't give me support for keytool.

Comment: You need to import them all into the *same* keystore file, and use that as your truststore.

Comment: @EJP I hardly suggest to NOT use the keystore as truststore.

Comment: @PeterRader That's a very unclear statement. I certainly don't recommend using the same file for both keystore and truststore. I should have said 'KeyStore' file or perhaps JKS file.

Comment: @EJP **Them all** guides me and others to mean the private and public keys. Could you elaborate`?

Comment: @PeterRader What private keys? There are no private keys mentioned in the question. I am talking about all the certificates that the OP is asking about.

Comment: @EJP tls requires bidirectional communication, so the server and the client(browser) must decrypt messages so they need their private keys that has been stored in their keystore (jks usually in servers, p7b usually in windows). You are not talking about the certificates, you are talking about the keys, thats why we call it keystore and not certificatestore.

Comment: @PeterRader You can be certain that when I say I am talking about the certificates, I mean it. The question is about 'SSL Certificate X.509 Export', and that is what my comment refers to. He is asking about what to do with the Entrust Root and Intermediate CA certificates. Please stick to the point.

Comment: @PeterRader And TLS's bidirectional communication is done via a symmetric session key, not by both sides having public/private key pairs, as I've already told you. The normal usage is that only the server has a certificate and a private key.

Comment: @EJP OP is asking about mutual authentication, he wrote *from they website and I imported that certificate in my local environment*.  The local environment is the keystore and the truststore of the client's os, not the keystore and truststore of the server.

Answer (score 1):

To do **client authentication** (also called mutual authentication) in SSL/TLS you (your program) needs not just a certificate but a **certificate PLUS PRIVATE KEY** and usually intermediate/chain certs. There are canonically 5 steps in the process:

1. On your computer generate a key PAIR which consists of a privatekey and a publickey, and a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) which contains the publickey. These steps may be done separately, or combined in a way that you don't notice there are both a CSR and a privatekey.
2. Submit the CSR to a Certificate Authority (CA) along with evidence of your identity and authorization as appropriate, and payment if the CA requres it.
3. The CA issues an 'end-entity' certificate (in this case a client cert) containing your publickey and identity(ies) plus some other information and gives you this certificate, usually along with an intermediate certificate or sometimes a few intermediate certs that form(s) a 'chain' from the entity cert to a trusted CA root or anchor cert. A 'p7b' file is one fairly common way, though not the only one, of transporting a group of related certs, such as your entity cert plus your chain cert(s).
4. You return the entity cert and the chain cert(s) to your computer and combine with your privatekey from step 1.
5. You use the combination of privatekey PLUS certificate chain with various program(s) such as a browser, a utility like `curl`, or a custom application.

Details of steps 1 and 4 (and 5) depend on the systems and software you use, which you don't specify in any recognizable way, although it sounds like you are ending up in the Windows certificate store. If that is the case, and it is specifically the Personal section of the current-user store (as opposed to a machine account like SYSTEM), then when you run MMC (aka Administrative Tools) and select the Cert Mgr addin, or directly run `certmgr.msc`, the icon for the cert should have a yellow key at the left:

[image: certmgr with privatekey]

Contrary to your Q, Java JCE (at least Oracle-was-Sun Java on Windows) *can* handle this; run `keytool -list -storetype Windows-MY -keystore NONE` and see for yourself.

However, some (probably many) Java *programs* cannot. For those, you need a keystore file containing the privatekey PLUS certificates; to create that run the Export wizard and select 'Yes, export private key', then format PKCS 12 (aka PFX) with 'include ... path'.

Recent updates of Java 8 by default can automatically handle a PKCS12 keystore (look for `keystore.type.compat=true` in `JRE/lib/security/java.security`) and older versions can do so if the program configures the store type (I don't know if SoapUI does that). For older versions that require JKS, after exporting to PKCS12 to let's say `mykey.p12` convert with

```
 keytool -importkeystore -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srckeystore mykey.p12 -destkeystore mykey.jks
```

Answer (score -1):

What you try to archivee is something called a mutual-authentication. In order to understand the basics you need to understand that the humans have simply concepted a password to lock and unlock informations by the same (symetric) password. Everyone who knows the one password can

1. read the message
2. rewrite the message to send false informations

this is dangerous. So they have invented two different passwords, one for writing (private) and a compleatly different one for receive(public), we call them asymetric. The problem in asymetric encryption was, that you can choose free only one password, the opposite password is calculated and can not be choosen freely.

Finally they invented certificates to simplify the process. Certificates contains strong Passwords packed into files. Without looking into the certificates you dont know if the passwords are private or public, that means p7b(pkcsv7b) and jks can contain the absolute same informations. The difference is the format only, like the difference between `.doc` and `.docx`.

### The second problem

In the big japaneese war's spionage was a big thing, the agents gathered informations about the opposite at the point of tactics and send theese informations to their real lords to find weaknesses in the tactics/strategys. Whenever a spoin has been uncovered he has been turned into a double-agent faking honeypots to let the warlord make wrong decisions and fall into traps.

So as an warlord you must trust your agent ... but, how to be sure? Well, you can ask the other agents about the agent you have the informations from to have the guarantee that the message can be trusted. So the first agent must ask other agents to sign the message too, this question between agents is the CSR! If the other agent(s) sign too, we have a "chain of trust". Ok we have four parties now, the agent, the signing-agent(s) the enemy(hacker) and you.

What must be placed where? Well, assuming you are a warlord (server),

1. you need the public passwords of all your clients(agents) in a truststore to send them messages(download),
2. you need to know your private password to encode messages(posts, requests, uploads) your agents sent.

Assuming you are a agent(client/browser) of a warlord inside the enemys lines (open field of world-wide-web), you must store:

1. your private key, to send messages and sign messages of other agents
2. the public key of the warlord to encode orders of your master.

You have learned now that a certificate can contain aswell private keys as public keys. How to technically use them?

You lucky, the keytools is open source, download the sources from grepcode ([click here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java)) and you will have your implementations by copy-and-paste.

Some hints for mutual-authentication:

1. The server should not offer its public certificate because all authenticated clients already have the public certificate(key) in their truststore.
2. The client's certificate should be sent in a non-electronic way (printed as rf-code or whatever).
3. The client should presented the server's public key and the clients private key in two seperate physical letters (you may noticed if you use the electronic-cash-card (ec-card) you had two letters, one for the PIN and one for the ec-card).

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. They are keys, not passwords. Being unable to choose freely isn't a problem. Certificates don't contain private keys. The sentence starting 'without looking into the certificates' is a *non sequitur*. Certificates cannot contain private keys. The server must offer its certificate. The client usually doesn't already have the server certificate. The client should generate his own private key. TLS does not use asymmetric encryption for messages at all, let alone in the nonsensical way described here. Far too much misinformation and sheer nonsense here.

Comment: @EJP no, Sure can Certificate-Files contain private keys! See this screenshot: http://www.herongyang.com/PKI/Internet-Options-Import-Private-Key.jpg It answers the question and more. It gives a kickstart into security, the difference between symetric and asymetric encryption that you are unable to share.

Comment: There is no evidence in your linked screenshot about a certificate containing a private key. It evidently refers to updating a key store file of some kind. It doesn't give a 'kickstart into security' either. If you mean your answer is a 'kickstart', all it really is is a false start. It would be a lot better without all the errors, and without all the junk about Japanese warlords too. If certificates contained private keys, private keys wouldn't be private.

Comment: @EJP The screenshot shows a dialog, the title of the dialog is "Certificate import wizard" so its realy going about importing certificates into the local trustsstore. The dialog asks for "Type the password for the private key" what makes it clear: There is a private key inside the certificate. I can not get it that i must read the dialog for you! EJP, I was member of pkix working group of ietf, trust me!

Comment: It is asking for the password of the *existing* private key, that is already in the key store,and that was the starting point of the CSR process, which is being completed by this import of the CA-signed certificate. If the private key had been sent to or supplied by the CA it would no longer be private and could not fulfil the purpose for which it was designed and created, i.e. uniquely identifying the client in a legally non-repudiable way. It is very difficult to believe your final assertion when your knowledge of TLS and certificate processes is so inaccurate.

Comment: @EJP see another screenshot: https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/article_attachments/201920381/exp_iis7_09.png showing the export of a certificate from iis7, asking for export the private key too. "You can choose to export the private key with the certificate.". You are right in the point that it is not a good idea to let the server generate a private key for the client, but most guys have no experiences in generating private keys by themselfes. Thats why i suggest in the 3rd of my hints to transport that certificate having the private key shipped physically like banks do it.

Comment: It is impossible to tell what these random screenshots are really for without some proper context. I suspect there is some confusion here between certifcate files and PKCS#12 keystore files, which should not emanate from such a source.

Comment: @EJP they are self-explained, but you are too proud to accept.